Python3 dcg_score via sklearn is different from keras LTR
Confusion in calculating DCG scores via sklearn and keras LTR.
y_true = [[1,7,3.0,4,6, 8]]
y_pred = [[1,2,3.0,4,5, 0.1]]

import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score, dcg_score
s = dcg_score(np.asarray(y_true),  np.asarray(y_pred))
print('sklearn dcg_score:', s,)

import tensorflow_ranking as tfr
dcg = tfr.keras.metrics.DCGMetric()
s = dcg(np.asarray(y_true),  np.asarray(y_pred)).numpy()
print('keras tfr ranking dcg_score:', s)

sklearn dcg_score: 16.274965224898303
keras tfr ranking dcg_score: 221.87955

I am really confused.  What am i missing?
